# More warning on doomed questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I've just had a question closed while I was composing a lengthy answer to it. This hasn't been the first time, and every time it happens I get the urge to trade in my keyboard for a machine gun and... well anyway, I get *very* upset.

If close-votes are coming in while I compose an answer, I want to know about it as they come in, not after the question has turned into a pumpkin.

Comment: I hate when that happens.

Comment: @I hate haikus - You seem to hate a lot of things.

Answer (score 12):

If we can see that new answers have been posted we should also see that the question we're answering or editing has been closed. This cuts down on frustration and allows us to focus on other things.

Answer (score 5):

There is a sort of "escrow" timer in place for answers in progress.  If, while you are composing an answer, a question gets closed, generally you can complete your response *within your open window*, post the answer, and it will get incorporated into the question.

Comment: Yep. I got the benefit of that on the "chair" question here on Meta.

Comment: Interesting! Is this documented anywhere? And can you tell us more about it, such as how long the grace time is?

Comment: The amount of time is probably the time between polling periods.  Each poll checks for new answers and closed questions.  I don't know how long the time interval is.